# Retrieving words with colon, and associated data

Tags: php, regex

I have data formatted as such:

`some words go here priority: p1,p2 -rank:3 status: not delayed`

Basically I need to retrieve each set of data that corresponds to the colon name.

Ideally if I could end up with an array structure such that

```
keywords => 'some words go here'
priority => 'p1,p2'
-rank    => 3
status   => 'not delayed'
```

A few caveats:

1. keywords will not have a defining colon-word (keywords are just placed in the front)
2. keywords will not always exist (might just be colon-words)
3. colon-words will not always exist (might just be keywords)

I imagine regex will have to be used to parse this out, but this goes beyond my understanding of regex.
If there is a simpler approach to this I'd be happy to find out.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: [Here's a start](http://regex101.com/r/yM0wO1)

Comment: Use `preg_split()`: `$arr = preg_split('/\s(?=\S+:\s*\S+)/', $str);` —  [**See demo**](https://eval.in/147346).

Comment: @Hamza That worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression will certainly be a much more elegant approach to this as @HamZa showed, but here's a proof of concept to illustrate that you could just brute force the solution. Keep in mind, this is a proof of concept, I won't be doing your entire assignment for you ;)

```
<?php
$string = "keywords go here priority: p1,p2 -rank:3 status: not delayed";

$kv = array();

$key = "keywords";
$substrings = explode(":", $string);

foreach($substrings as $k => $substring) {
        $pieces = explode(" ", $substring);

        $chunk = $k == count($substrings) - 1 ? 0 : 1;

        $kv[$key] = trim(join(" ", array_slice($pieces, 0, count($pieces)-$chunk)));
        $key = $pieces[count($pieces)-1];
}

print_r($kv);

// Array
// (
//   [keywords] => keywords go here
//   [priority] => p1,p2
//   [-rank] => 3
//   [status] => not delayed
// )
```